# How can I get popular tags/keywords from a collection of unstructured text chunks?

Tags: full-text-search, text-analysis

I am storing small chunks of texts - say of around 100 - 200 words - in a NoSQL database, and need to display the trending keywords/tags among all of these chunks.

I know of text analysis APIs like alchemy which extract entities from a single chunk of text, but I want top keywords/tags among all the chunks.

Should I store keywords against each text-chunk and then do an exhaustive counting of the top keywords? In which case, each keyword may differ slightly and may lead to fragmentation of similar keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Its not always necessary that filtering out entities would provide you the result (thought it serves a basic purpose). If you want it to be more effective you should remove the stopwords, do stemming, UpperCase to LowerCase converstion, spelling correction and then use a HashMap to find frequencies.
Using this frequency you can filter out top 100-200 entities/tags.

I hope this helps.